# Name for the growth of $n^n$ in big-O

Tags: algorithms, terminology, asymptotics

I know that $f=k^n$ is exponential growth and $f=n$ is linear, but what about $f=n^n$? What is the name of the last function's growth in big-O notation? Is there a specific term for that?

Comment: It's not their combination, nor does it have a specific name that I know of. You may go with "factorial growth" (though that's not exactly it) or "superexponential growth" (though that refers to anything faster than exponential, i.e., is much broader).

Comment: thanks for suggestion! I need to contrast (compare) this n^n growth with factorial, so 'superexponential growth' term would probably be better, right?

Comment: Yeah, but it applies to both of them.

Comment: oh, I see, it means that it can confuse people a bit as well in my situation. I will call it "n to the n-th power growth" when comparing it with "factorial growth".

Answer (score 0):

You can say that $\log(f)$ is $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ since $n^n = (e^{\log n})^n = e^{n \log n}$.